# Trying to understand a proof on representation of $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

I am trying to understand a proof of Proposition 3.1.2 from [Bohle - $K$-theory
for
Ternary Structures](https://d-nb.info/1027017371/34#page39). Let me explain the notations below.

Let $V$ be a TRO (a closed subspace of $B(H,K)$ which is closed under the ternary product $(x,y,z) \to xy^*z$). Put $V^*=\{x^*: x \in V \}$ and let $C(V)$ and $D(V)$  denote the $C^*$-algebras generated by $VV^*$ and $V^*V$, respectively. The linking $C^*$-algebra of $V$ is defined to be $$A(V)=
\begin{bmatrix}C(V)& V\\V^* &  D(V)\end{bmatrix} \subset B(K \oplus H).$$

Observe that $B(H,K)$ itself is a TRO and $$A(B(H,K))=
\begin{bmatrix}B(K)& B(H,K)\\B(K,H) &  B(H)\end{bmatrix}=B(K\oplus H).$$

> Let $V$ be a TRO and $\pi :A(V) \to B(H)$ be a representation of the linking $C^*$-algebra $A(V)$. We identify $V$, $C(V)$ and $D(V)$ with their images in $A(V)$. Define $ H_1=\overline{ \pi(C(V))H}$ and $K_1= H_1^{\perp}$ then $H= H_1 \oplus K_1$. There exists a canonical isomorphism $\rho$ between $B(H)$ and $A(B(H_1, K_1))=B(K_1 \oplus K_1)$. Let $\zeta = \rho \circ \pi$. Then in the linked proof it is written that $$\zeta(C(V))\subset 
> \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0  &  B(H_1)\end{bmatrix}, \zeta(D(V))\subset 
> \begin{bmatrix}B(K_1) & 0 \\0  &  0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Could someone please explain the last inclusions?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you don't say what $T$ nor $L(V)$ are.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Edited, thanks. If something is still unclear, please let me know.